# Write a CSV file with delimiter in a cell (two points)

Tags: python, csv

How do I write to a `.csv` file the following:

```
1171837, 1974:3655:1862:279:1936
1172, 238:1833:228:234:1821:225:211:245:1941:315:2035:222:3371:231:224:216:1942
```

instead of this:

```
1171837, ['1974', '3655', '1862', '279', '1936']
1172, ['238', '1833', '228', '234', '1821', '225', '211', '245', '1941', '315', '2035', '222', '3371', '231', '224', '216', '1942']
```

These are the lists that I have:

```
lche=['1171837', '1172']
ltarg=[['1974', '3655', '1862', '279', '1936'],
       ['238', '1833', '228', '234', '1821', '225', '211', '245', '1941',
        '315', '2035', '222', '3371', '231', '224', '216', '1942']]
```

This is the way how I did it. I do not know how use other delimiters.

```
data="list.csv"
csv_out = open(data, 'wb')
mywriter = csv.writer(csv_out)
for row in zip(lche,ltarg):
    mywriter.writerow(row)
csv_out.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [join](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=join#str.join) the elements of `ltarg` together with a colon:

```
>>> ltarg2 = list()
>>> for elem in ltarg:
...     ltarg2.append(':'.join(elem))
...     
>>> ltarg2
['1974:3655:1862:279:1936', '238:1833:228:234:1821:225:211:245:1941:315:2035:222:3371:231:224:216:1942']
```

Then continue as you were with the new list:

```
for row in zip(lche,ltarg2):
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `join`

Try:

```
import csv
lche=['1171837', '1172']
ltarg=[['1974', '3655', '1862', '279', '1936'], ['238', '1833', '228', '234', '1821', '225', '211', '245', '1941', '315', '2035', '222', '3371', '231', '224', '216', '1942']]

data="list.csv"
csv_out = open(data, 'wb')
mywriter = csv.writer(csv_out)
l = [':'.join(x) for x in ltarg]
for row in zip(lche,l):
    mywriter.writerow(row)
csv_out.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to combine (`join`) the sub-lists in `ltarg` into single strings while `zip`ping its contents with the `lche` list.

```
import csv

lche = ['1171837', '1172']
ltarg = [['1974', '3655', '1862', '279', '1936'],
         ['238', '1833', '228', '234', '1821', '225', '211', '245', '1941', 
          '315', '2035', '222', '3371', '231', '224', '216', '1942']]

data = "list.csv"
with open(data, 'wb') as csv_out:
    mywriter = csv.writer(csv_out)
    for row in zip(lche, (':'.join(v for v in lt) for lt in ltarg)):
        mywriter.writerow(row)
```

Contents of the `list.csv` file afterwards:

```
1171837,1974:3655:1862:279:1936
1172,238:1833:228:234:1821:225:211:245:1941:315:2035:222:3371:231:224:216:1942
```